# Synapses Serverless Pool -Read External Tables

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to read the data from external table which is configured in synapses serverless pool using pyspark notebook (I want that to be in a dataframe), however i am not able to do that.
Can someone guide me how we can do that. I tried the following code.

```
server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://<<sservername>>-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net"
database_name = "<<dbname>>"
url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"

table_name = "dbo.NameList"
username = "sqladmin"
password = "<<password>>" # Please specify password here
driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

namelistdf = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name )\
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("driver", driverClass) \
    .load()

namelistdf.show()
namelistdf.createOrReplaceTempView('namelistdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of the external data source, there are two types of external tables:

- **Hadoop external tables** that you can use to read and export data in various data formats such as CSV, Parquet, and ORC. Hadoop
  external tables are available in dedicated SQL pools, but they aren't
  available in serverless SQL pools.
- **Native external tables** that you can use to read and export data in various data formats such as CSV and Parquet. Native external
  tables are available in serverless SQL pools, and they are in public
  preview in dedicated SQL pools.

Make sure you have a Native external table which is stored in your Primary storage account and then you can use below sample code to read the file using pyspark.

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://users@contosolake.dfs.core.windows.net/NYCTripSmall.parquet', format='parquet')
display(df.limit(10))
```

Refer [Use external tables with Synapse SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=hadoop) and [Analyze with Apache Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-spark#main) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

First, the Error you received would have been helpful. If @Utkarsh Pal´s answer was not the solution I give it a shot.

You likely received an permission-error like this -> 
*Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3900.load. : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'https://blablalake.blob.core.windows.net/bla/blabla.parquet', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.*

There are a couple of things to be done **before** you are able to access data from a serverless sql pool with Synapse-notebooks.

1. **add your Synapse-Identity and your user** as "**Storage Blob Data Contributor**" in Access Control of your Storage-Account:
   [image]
2. next, **BEFORE** creating the external table, you have to **define a master key, scoped credentials, and an external data scource USING these credentials**!!!
   [image]

3. create an external table **based on this external data source**.

The Credentials are now in place and you can use your above method to query your external table with pyspark.